# Install CentOS on the same hard disk where Ubuntu resides

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, hard-disk

I'm planing to install CentOS on the same hard disk where Ubuntu exists. 
Am I able to do that or do I risk losing Ubuntu? Will the grub give me the choice to select between OSes upon boot?

P.S. I have 500 GB on the hard disk and Ubuntu only takes up 8 %.

Answer (score 0):

In case you aren't aware, your hard disk is divided into *partitions*.

If you try to install CentOS on the *same* partition as Ubuntu, you will end up trashing the Ubuntu installation.

To resolve this, you just need to create a *new* partition for the CentOS installation.

Boot from the Ubuntu live CD/USB, as it is not a good idea to resize partitions on a running system, and besides, you probably won't be able to anyway. Open GParted and resize (i.e. reduce) the Ubuntu partition (and any other associated partitions, that you may have created). You could get away with making it just 10 GB, but 100 GB or so would be more sensible, in the long run.

Then make an additional partition, again 50 - 100 GB, and install CentOS on to that *new* partition.

If you don't plan on adding any other OSes, beyond CentOS, then you could just split the hard disk into two partitions, giving each 250 GB. Note that there are probably other partitions present, i.e. swap, and you will want to keep these as they are, and not reduce their size.

Comment: that's enlightening thanks!! i'll try the steps suggested and see if everything will go right.